# Implementing FIFO in SQL

Tags: sql, algorithm, fifo

I'm working with retail. 
In retail we have suppliers that supply products and we have customers that buy these products. Sometimes happens that two different suppliers supply the same product almost at the same day. So I have to figure out what products was sold by first supply and what products was sold by second supply using FIFO algorithm. And update table with cart items to specify supplier per each item.

I have two tables:

```
supplies

+----------------------------+-------------+---------+------------+----------+
| supply_date                | supplier_id | shop_id | product_id | quantity |
+----------------------------+-------------+---------+------------+----------+
| 2019-03-29 12:00:00.000000 | 5           | 2       | 1          | 110      |
+----------------------------+-------------+---------+------------+----------+
| 2019-03-29 16:00:00.000000 | 7           | 2       | 1          | 50       |
+----------------------------+-------------+---------+------------+----------+
| 2019-04-01 13:00:00.000000 | 6           | 3       | 8          | 30       |
+----------------------------+-------------+---------+------------+----------+
| 2019-04-02 16:00:00.000000 | 8           | 3       | 8          | 90       |
+----------------------------+-------------+---------+------------+----------+
| 2019-04-29 10:00:00.000000 | 1           | 5       | 6          | 25       |
+----------------------------+-------------+---------+------------+----------+

cartitems

+-----------+----------------------------+---------+------------+----------+
| id        | date                       | shop_id | product_id | quantity |
+-----------+----------------------------+---------+------------+----------+
| 515037984 | 2019-04-01 14:25:50.000000 | 2       | 1          | 30       |
+-----------+----------------------------+---------+------------+----------+
| 515043777 | 2019-04-02 13:47:52.000000 | 3       | 8          | 25       |
+-----------+----------------------------+---------+------------+----------+
| 515045460 | 2019-04-02 20:14:30.000000 | 2       | 1          | 80       |
+-----------+----------------------------+---------+------------+----------+
| 515046099 | 2019-04-09 09:55:53.000000 | 2       | 1          | 10       |
+-----------+----------------------------+---------+------------+----------+
| 515046332 | 2019-04-09 11:06:30.000000 | 2       | 1          | 5        |
+-----------+----------------------------+---------+------------+----------+
```

I have tried something and it works but too slow. UPDATE .. FROM statement works very slow.
Function below uses FIFO algorithm and updates `cartitems` table with `supplier_id` column.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION attach_suppliers(shop INTEGER, product INTEGER) RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
  DECLARE
    -- VARIABLES TO USE
    supply_quantity DECIMAL;
    var_supplier_id INTEGER;
    supply_date TIMESTAMP;
    sale_quantity DECIMAL;
    cartitem_id INTEGER;

    -- SIMPLE COUNTER
    updated_count INTEGER = 0;

    -- CURSOR FOR MOVING ROW BY ROW IN A QUERY WITH SUPPLIES
    supplies_cursor CURSOR FOR
      SELECT quantity, supplier_id, supply_date
      FROM supplies s
      WHERE s.shop_id = $1 AND s.product_id = $2
      ORDER BY s.supply_date ASC;

    -- CURSOR FOR MOVING ROW BY ROW IN A QUERY WITH CARTITEMS
    sales_cursor CURSOR (start_date TIMESTAMP) FOR
      SELECT id, quantity
      FROM cartitems s
      WHERE s.shop_id = $1 AND s.product_id = $2 AND s.date > start_date
      ORDER BY s.date ASC;

  BEGIN
    -- TEMP TABLES TO SAVE REFERENCE BETWEEN CART ITEM AND SUPPLIER
    CREATE TEMP table citem_supplier_mapping (
      _cartitem_id INTEGER,
      _supplier_id INTEGER
    );

    -- STARTING FROM THE FIRST ROW FROM BOTH TABLES
    OPEN supplies_cursor;

    FETCH NEXT FROM supplies_cursor INTO supply_quantity, var_supplier_id, supply_date;

    OPEN sales_cursor(start_date := supply_date);

    FETCH NEXT FROM sales_cursor INTO sale_quantity, cartitem_id;

    -- LOOP THROUGH CART ITEMS
    LOOP
      -- CURRENT ITERATION SHOWS US REFERENCE BETWEEN CART ITEM AND SUPPLIER
      supply_quantity := supply_quantity - sale_quantity;
      INSERT INTO citem_supplier_mapping (_cartitem_id, _supplier_id) VALUES (cartitem_id, var_supplier_id);
      updated_count := updated_count + 1;

      -- IF ALL SUPPLIED PRODUCTS WERE SOLD THEN GO TO THE NEXT SUPPLY
      IF supply_quantity <= 0 THEN
        FETCH NEXT FROM supplies_cursor INTO supply_quantity, var_supplier_id, supply_date;
        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
      END IF;

      -- GO TO THE NEXT CART ITEM
      FETCH NEXT FROM sales_cursor INTO sale_quantity, cartitem_id;
      EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
    END LOOP;

    -- UPDATE CART ITEMS TABLE WITH `supplier_id` COLUMN TO MAKE REFERENCE
    UPDATE cartitems SET supplier_id = _supplier_id FROM citem_supplier_mapping WHERE id = _cartitem_id;

    -- CLEAN UP
    DROP TABLE citem_supplier_mapping;
    CLOSE supplies_cursor;
    CLOSE sales_cursor;

    RETURN updated_count;
  END; $$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

As a result I expect table like this (or just a mapping between cartitem_id and supplier_id):

```
+-----------+----------------------------+---------+------------+----------+-------------+
| id        | date                       | shop_id | product_id | quantity | supplier_id |
+-----------+----------------------------+---------+------------+----------+-------------+
| 515037984 | 2019-04-01 14:25:50.000000 | 2       | 1          | 30       | 5           |
+-----------+----------------------------+---------+------------+----------+-------------+
| 515043777 | 2019-04-02 13:47:52.000000 | 3       | 8          | 25       | 6           |
+-----------+----------------------------+---------+------------+----------+-------------+
| 515045460 | 2019-04-02 20:14:30.000000 | 2       | 1          | 80       | 5           |
+-----------+----------------------------+---------+------------+----------+-------------+
| 515046099 | 2019-04-09 09:55:53.000000 | 2       | 1          | 10       | 7           |
+-----------+----------------------------+---------+------------+----------+-------------+
| 515046332 | 2019-04-09 11:06:30.000000 | 2       | 1          | 5        | 7           |
+-----------+----------------------------+---------+------------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: Don't use Cursors, they are slow. You should be able to do a set based approach.

Comment: Does it matter if it is slow? Shouldn't it be a one time operation? Can't you add a supplies_id column to the cartitems table, so that you don't have to do this again? Probably easiest if you add a column to the supplies table too which shows how much is left, then you can set the supplies_id on insertion to the cartitems table with relatively simple SQL (and update the quantity that is left in the corresponding row in the supplies table).